# StackOverflowException on a huge class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, stack-overflow

So, I got to work on this huge project. And the is this HUGE class with hundreds of variables and methods and lots of partial classes.

```
interface IBusinessReturn
{

    string variableOne { get; set; }
    string variableTwo { get; set; }

    string variableHundred { get; set; }
    //a lot more...
 }

 public partial class BusinessTransaction : IBusinessReturn
{

    private string _variableOne;
    public string variableOne
    {
        get { return variableOne; }
        set { _variableOne= value; }
    }

    private string _variableTwo;
    public string variableTwo
    {
        get { return variableTwo; }
        set { _variableTwo = value; }
    }

    private string _variableHundred;
    public string variableHundred
    {
        get { return variableHundred; }
        set { _variableHundred = value; }
    }

    // And so it goes on till hundreds...
}
```

And lots of other partials that goes like this:

```
public partial class BusinessTransaction: IBusinessTransaction238
{
   //Lots of methods
}
```

The problem is: It is all working except for some new variables I declared. (varOne and Two, in the example above). When I try to set any value to these var I got a **StackOverflowException**. I'm 100% sure they're declared just like every other.

This is how i'm calling:

```
 BusinessTransaction v763 = new BusinessTransaction();

 v763.variableHundred = "Hi"; //working
 v763.variableOne = "Hello"; //StackOverflow HERE.
```

I just can't see any reason for why this is happening, and I only hope you can tell me if this have something to do with the huge amount of methods and variables on this class..

Comment: Is this inside some type of loop?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `{ get; set; }` syntax that implements the getters and setters automatically?

Comment: In C# it's recommended for public members to be PascalCased not camelCased.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at your getter - no underscores for any of them. You're causing an infinite loop.

```
public string variableOne
{
    get { return variableOne; }
    set { _variableOne= value; }
}
```

Comment: yeah that was it. Hours on top of something and you just can't see those kind of things. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should return private member, not itself.

Should be

```
public string variableOne
{
    get { return _variableOne; // error was here
    }
    set { _variableOne= value; }
}
```